# Non personalized banner ad not visible via Admob

Tags: android, admob

I've added GDPR consent to my game. Everything works fine beside that ad banner is not visible when I want to show non personalized ads. I get this info all the time:

> "No fill from ad server." and "Failed to load ad: 3"

Interstitial ad works great. I'm using google play services ads:

> "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.0"

Here is my code to create non personalized ad request:

```
_adBuilder = new Builder();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString( "npa", "1" );
_adBuilder.addNetworkExtrasBundle( AdMobAdapter.class, extras );
```

I have my game ported to iOS and there everything works fine - banner ad is visible.

Comment: hello, could you solve it? I am having the same problem and cannot find a solution.